# The limit of $f_n = \frac {e^x \sin(x) \sin(2x) \cdots \sin(nx)}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> I want to calculate a limit of $f_n = \frac {e^x \sin(x) \sin(2x) \cdots
>  \sin(nx)}{\sqrt n}$ if $n$ goes to an infinity.

I was wondering if I can use this: $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\sin(nx)}{n} = 0$, because I have doubts.

I know that $$  \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x) =  \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$$ (or I suppose), but what if the limit of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is zero

My attempt of a solution:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {e^x \sin(x) \sin(2x) ...
\sin(nx)}{\sqrt n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\sqrt ne^x \sin(x) \sin(2x) ...
\sin(nx)}{ n}\\ = \lim_{n\to \infty}  {\sqrt ne^x \sin(x) \sin(2x)}  \frac {\sin(nx)}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}  {\sqrt ne^x \sin(x) \sin(2x)} * 0 = 0$$

And the range for the convergence is $\infty$ , right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\sin(x)$ is always between 1 and 0. But the denominator keeps getting larger as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Isn't the magnitude of the numerator less than $e^x$, which does not depend on $n$, hence pointwise convergence ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon: my bad, I believed we were requested to prove uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

The pointwise convergence towards zero is trivial, we may actually prove we have uniform convergence over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let
$$ g_n(x) = \sin(x)\sin(2x)\cdots \sin(nx). $$
The supremum of $g_n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is attained at a point of the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$. Due to the approximation $\sin(x)\leq x e^{-x^2/6}$ over the interval $(0,\pi)$ we have
$$ \sup g_n(x) \leq \sup n! x^n \exp\left(-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{36}x^2\right)= n!\left(\frac{18}{e(n+1)(2n+1)}\right)^{n/2}$$
and 
$$ \sup g_n(x) \leq \frac{6}{5}\sqrt{n}\,e^{-\frac{2}{5}n}. $$
It follows that on the interval $\left[-\frac{n}{5},\frac{n}{5}\right]$ the absolute value of $f_n(x)$ is bounded by $\frac{6}{5}e^{-n/5}$.
This bound implies U.C. towards zero on any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It seems that $\sin(x)\leq x e^{-x^2/6}$ only holds for $0\leq x\leq 2\pi$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon: right, fixed.

Comment: How do you prove this inequality btw ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon: by exploiting the Weierstrass product for the sine function, for instance, or by applying $\exp\int\frac{(\ldots)}{z}\,dz$ to both sides of $z\cot z\geq 1-z^2/3$.

Comment: You definitely have many tricks up your sleeve, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

For a given $x$, we can show that $\inf \{ m\cdot x - n\cdot\pi: m, n \in {\mathbb Z}\} = 0$.  Thus, $|\sin mx|$ can be made arbitrarily small by proper choice of $m$. The other sine factors and the $1/\sqrt n $ factor reduce the modulus, and the $e^x$ factor is fixed.  The limit is, therefore, 0.